# Properly DELETE 500k+ Rows from Multiple Tables in a Single Script

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, delete

There are several examples all over the Internet and StackOverflow on how to properly delete 500k+ rows from a single table and COMMIT those DELETES in Batches.

I am unsure of how to incorporate these examples into a much larger more complex script that DELETEs related data from multiple tables or how to do it properly while also providing meaningful incremental Output.

Back Story: My original script which only includes basic deletes based off of data loaded into a Temp Table took 54 minutes and locked up my entire Train database and in turn locked up the application.  I absolutely cannot run this script in Production however I need to and I need to do it without locking resources.

**Original DELETE Script.  I removed many tables in this Example but listed how many tables are in the original script for reference**

```
/* This version locks recourses and takes 54 minutes to run in Train.  This will lock up my Production Database and application. */
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #ImportedAssessments

            SELECT a.AssessmentID,a.ClientID
            INTO #ImportedAssessments
            FROM dbo.Assessment a
            INNER JOIN dbo.Clients c ON c.ClientID = a.ClientID 
            INNER JOIN [_ConversionData].[Schema].[ParticipantData] p ON p.pcc_id = c.ImportReferenceID

        -------     Client Interview 4 Tables   ------------------


            DELETE cs
            FROM CT_CurrLivingStatus cs
            INNER JOIN CT_ClientInterview ci ON ci.ClientInterviewID = cs.ClientInterviewID
            INNER JOIN #ImportedAssessments a ON a.AssessmentID = ci.AssessmentID

            DELETE er
            FROM CT_SvcEntryRisk er
            INNER JOIN CT_ClientInterview ci ON ci.ClientInterviewID = er.ClientInterviewID 
            INNER JOIN #ImportedAssessments a ON a.AssessmentID = ci.AssessmentID

            DELETE s
            FROM CT_ClientInterview ci
            INNER JOIN #ImportedAssessments a ON a.AssessmentID = ci.AssessmentID
            INNER JOIN dbo.Service s ON s.TableID = ci.ClientInterviewID AND s.TableName =  'CT_ClientInterview'

            DELETE ci
            FROM CT_ClientInterview ci
            INNER JOIN #ImportedAssessments a ON a.AssessmentID = ci.AssessmentID

        -------     Brief Risk  Assessment 5 Tables ------------------

            DELETE  ro
            FROM CT_RiskAssessment ci
            INNER JOIN #ImportedAssessments a ON a.AssessmentID = ci.AssessmentID
            INNER JOIN CT_RiskOptions ro ON ro.ParentID = ci.RiskAssessmentID

            --Tables removed for example

        ----------------------  HIVHCV Testing 12 Tables        ----------------------------    


            DELETE pr
            FROM CT_HIVHCVTesting ci
            INNER JOIN #ImportedAssessments a ON a.AssessmentID = ci.AssessmentID
            INNER JOIN CT_HIVPositiveReferrals pr ON pr.ParentID = ci.HIVHCVTestingID

            --Tables removed for example

        ----------------------  Referrals Education 3 Tables    ----------------------------    


            DELETE ep
            FROM CT_ReferralsEducation ci
            INNER JOIN #ImportedAssessments a ON a.AssessmentID = ci.AssessmentID
            INNER JOIN CT_EducationProvided ep ON ep.ParentID = ci.ReferralsEducationID


            --Tables removed for example


        ----------------------  SSP SyringeServices 3 Tables    ----------------------------    

            DELETE sd
            FROM CT_SyringeServices ci
            INNER JOIN #ImportedAssessments a ON a.AssessmentID = ci.AssessmentID
            INNER JOIN CT_SyringesDisposedHow sd ON sd.ParentID = ci.SyringeServicesID

            --Tables removed for example

        ----------------------  SSP FentanylTestStrip 5 Tables  ----------------------------    

            DELETE du
            FROM CT_FentanylAssessment ci
            INNER JOIN #ImportedAssessments a ON a.AssessmentID = ci.AssessmentID
            INNER JOIN CT_FentanylTestStrips ts ON ts.FentanylAssessmentID = ci.FentanylAssessmentID    
            INNER JOIN CT_DrugUses du ON du.ParentID = ts.FentanylTestStripsID

            --Tables removed for example


        -----------     Master Assessment   2 Tables    -------------------------------

            DELETE ce
            FROM dbo.CUSTOM_Assessment ce
            INNER JOIN #ImportedAssessments a ON a.AssessmentID = ce.AssessmentID

            --Table removed for example

        ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    
        ROLLBACK; PRINT char(10) + 'NOTE: Transaction Rolled Back on Purpose (Testing)';
        --COMMIT; PRINT char(10) + 'NOTE: Transaction COMMITTED';
    
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK;
            PRINT 'Error occured: Open Transaction Detected.  Transaction ROLLED BACK';
        END
    
        /* DECLARE Individual Error Detail Variables */
        DECLARE @ErrorProcedure VARCHAR(200), @ErrorMessage     NVARCHAR(4000), @ErrorSeverity  VARCHAR(20), @ErrorLine     VARCHAR(20)
            , @ErrorState       VARCHAR(20) /* Error State = Level aka Severity Level */
        ;

        /* Store Individual Error Details in variables for later output */
        SELECT  @ErrorProcedure = ERROR_PROCEDURE(), @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(), @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE(), @ErrorLine = ERROR_LINE();
        --ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber

        /* RAISE the Error */
        RAISERROR(N'An error occurred in %s Deleting Assessment Records.  Level %s, State %s, Line %s, ErrorMsg: %s', 11, 2, @ErrorProcedure, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState, @ErrorLine, @ErrorMessage);
        RETURN;
    
    END CATCH

END
```

**My new DELETE Script includes many of the suggestions provided in chat.  I've added to comments within the script what updates I applied.  This new version no longer locks the database and users can still use the application while this script is running**

```
/*
 | Added TRANSACTION LOGIC.  
 | Wraps each table in a WHILE LOOP and a TRANSACTION
 | DELETEs Records using TOP(4500) for batches of 4500 per COMMIT
 | Outputs Time Stats in real time using RAISERROR.
 | Pull the Primary Keys of the records to be deleted into a Table Variable named @Pkeys to later DELETE using EXISTS
 | Prefixed each table with the dbo schema
*/

SET XACT_ABORT ON;  /* SET XACT_ABORT ON instructs SQL Server to rollback the entire transaction and abort the batch when a run-time error occurs. */


DECLARE @DateTimeBeg    DATETIME;    -- start datetime
DECLARE @DateTimeEnd    DATETIME;    -- end datetime

DECLARE @TimeString     VARCHAR(10); -- Store Time as a String for Output in RAISERROR

DECLARE @Rows           VARCHAR(10); -- For RAISERROR Output
DECLARE @RowsDeleted    INT;         -- For WHILE Loops

DECLARE @PKeys TABLE (TablePKey INT NOT NULL, UNIQUE (TablePKey) ); -- Store Primary Keys of records slated for Deletion
DECLARE @PKeysLoaded    INT;         -- This is to avoid loading the @PKeys Table Variable more than once while in the WHILE Loop

DECLARE @CRLF           VARCHAR(4) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);

BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY

    /* 34 Tables Total */
    
        SELECT @DateTimeBeg = GETDATE();
    
            /* Output Time Stats - Process BEGIN */
            SELECT @TimeString = CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), @DateTimeBeg , 108);
            RAISERROR(N'Process Started at %s', 0, 1, @TimeString ) WITH NOWAIT; WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';

            DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #ImportedAssessments

            SELECT a.AssessmentID, a.ClientID
            INTO #ImportedAssessments
            FROM dbo.Assessment a
            INNER JOIN dbo.Client c ON c.ClientID = a.ClientID 
            INNER JOIN [_ConversionData].[Schema].[ParticipantData] p ON p.pcc_id = c.ImportReferenceID
            ;

            -- Create a non-clustered index on the 'AssessmentID' column of the temp table
            CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_ImportedAssessments_AssessmentID ON #ImportedAssessments (AssessmentID);


        -------     Client Interview 4 Tables       ------------------


        RAISERROR(N'%sClient Interview Section DELETE', 0, 1, @CRLF) WITH NOWAIT; WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';
    
        /* Table 1/4 CT_CurrLivingStatus */
        DELETE FROM @PKeys;     -- Reset Table Variable
        SET @PKeysLoaded   = 0; -- Reset PKeysLoaded for the next WHILE Loop
        SET   @RowsDeleted = 1; -- Set to 1 to start WHILE Loop
        WHILE @RowsDeleted > 0
        BEGIN
            BEGIN TRANSACTION
            
                /* Gather PKeys into PKeys table variable for DELETion */
                IF @PKeysLoaded = 0   /* If @PKeysLoaded = 0 this means the data has not yet been loaded into @PKeys */
                BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @PKeys (TablePKey)
                SELECT cs.CurrLivingStatusID
                FROM dbo.CT_CurrLivingStatus cs
                INNER JOIN dbo.CT_ClientInterview ci ON ci.ClientInterviewID = cs.ClientInterviewID
                INNER JOIN #ImportedAssessments    a ON a.AssessmentID = ci.AssessmentID
                ;
                SET @PKeysLoaded = 1; /* Used to avoid loading the @PKeys TABLE Variable more than once WHILE in the Loop */
                END

                DELETE TOP(4500) cs
                FROM dbo.CT_CurrLivingStatus cs
                WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @PKeys pk WHERE pk.TablePKey = cs.CurrLivingStatusID )

                SET    @RowsDeleted = @@ROWCOUNT;
                SELECT @TimeString  = ISNULL( CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), GETDATE() , 108), 'NoTime' )
                        , @Rows     = ISNULL( CAST(@RowsDeleted AS VARCHAR(10)), 'NoRows' )
                ;
                RAISERROR(N'CT_CurrLivingStatus %s. Rows: %s', 0, 1, @TimeString, @Rows) WITH NOWAIT;  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';

            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END

        /* Table 2/4 CT_SvcEntryRisk */
        --SQL Removed for Example

        /* Table 3/4 Service Records for CT_ClientInterview */
        --SQL Removed for Example

        /* Table 4/4 CT_ClientInterview */
        --SQL Removed for Example

        -------     Brief Risk  Assessment 5 Tables ------------------


        RAISERROR(N'%sBrief Risk Section DELETE', 0, 1, @CRLF) WITH NOWAIT; WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';

        /* Table 1/5 CT_RiskOptions */
        DELETE FROM @PKeys;     -- Reset Table Variable
        SET @PKeysLoaded   = 0; -- Reset PKeysLoaded for the next WHILE Loop
        SET   @RowsDeleted = 1; -- Set to 1 to start WHILE Loop
        WHILE @RowsDeleted > 0
        BEGIN
            BEGIN TRANSACTION

                /* Gather PKeys into PKeys table variable for DELETion */
                IF @PKeysLoaded = 0   /* If @PKeysLoaded = 0 this means the data has not yet been loaded into @PKeys */
                BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @PKeys (TablePKey)
                SELECT ro.RiskOptionsID
                FROM dbo.CT_RiskAssessment ci
                INNER JOIN #ImportedAssessments a ON a.AssessmentID = ci.AssessmentID
                INNER JOIN dbo.CT_RiskOptions  ro ON ro.ParentID = ci.RiskAssessmentID
                ;
                SET @PKeysLoaded = 1; /* Used to avoid loading the @PKeys TABLE Variable more than once WHILE in the Loop */
                END

                DELETE TOP(4500) ro
                FROM dbo.CT_RiskOptions ro
                WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @PKeys pk WHERE pk.TablePKey = ro.RiskOptionsID )

                SET    @RowsDeleted = @@ROWCOUNT;
                SELECT @TimeString  = ISNULL( CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), GETDATE() , 108), 'NoTime' )
                        , @Rows     = ISNULL( CAST(@RowsDeleted AS VARCHAR(10)), 'NoRows' )
                ;
                RAISERROR(N'CT_RiskAssessment %s. Rows: %s', 0, 1, @TimeString, @Rows) WITH NOWAIT;  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';

            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END

        /* Table 2/5 CT_UsedSubstances */
        --SQL Removed for Example
    
        /* Table 3/5 CT_TobaccoTypes */
        --SQL Removed for Example

        /* Table 4/5 CT_CannabisTypes */
        --SQL Removed for Example

        /* Table 5/5 CT_RiskAssessment */
        --SQL Removed for Example


        ----------------------  HIVHCV Testing 12 Tables        ----------------------------


        RAISERROR(N'%sHIVHCV Testing Section DELETE', 0, 1, @CRLF) WITH NOWAIT; WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';


        /* Table 1/12 CT_HIVPositiveReferrals */
        DELETE FROM @PKeys;     -- Reset Table Variable
        SET @PKeysLoaded   = 0; -- Reset PKeysLoaded for the next WHILE Loop
        SET   @RowsDeleted = 1; -- Set to 1 to start WHILE Loop
        WHILE @RowsDeleted > 0
        BEGIN
            BEGIN TRANSACTION

                /* Gather PKeys into PKeys table variable for DELETion */
                IF @PKeysLoaded = 0   /* If @PKeysLoaded = 0 this means the data has not yet been loaded into @PKeys */
                BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @PKeys (TablePKey)
                SELECT pr.HIVPositiveReferralsID
                FROM dbo.CT_HIVHCVTesting hi
                INNER JOIN #ImportedAssessments         a ON a.AssessmentID = hi.AssessmentID
                INNER JOIN dbo.CT_HIVPositiveReferrals pr ON pr.ParentID    = hi.HIVHCVTestingID
                ;
                SET @PKeysLoaded = 1; /* Used to avoid loading the @PKeys TABLE Variable more than once WHILE in the Loop */
                END

                DELETE TOP(4500) pr
                FROM dbo.CT_HIVPositiveReferrals pr
                WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @PKeys pk WHERE pk.TablePKey = pr.HIVPositiveReferralsID )

                SET    @RowsDeleted = @@ROWCOUNT;
                SELECT @TimeString  = ISNULL( CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), GETDATE() , 108), 'NoTime' )
                        , @Rows     = ISNULL( CAST(@RowsDeleted AS VARCHAR(10)), 'NoRows' )
                ;
                RAISERROR(N'CT_HIVPositiveReferrals %s. Rows: %s', 0, 1, @TimeString, @Rows) WITH NOWAIT;  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';

            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END

        /* Table 2/12 CT_Symptoms */
        --SQL Removed for Example

        /* Table 3/12 CT_TestingStatus */
        --SQL Removed for Example

        /* Table 4/12 CT_HCVContacts */
        --SQL Removed for Example

        /* Table 5/12 CT_PreTestActivities */
        --SQL Removed for Example

        /* Table 6/12 CT_TattooLocations */
        --SQL Removed for Example

        /* Table 7/12 CT_PiercingLocations */
        --SQL Removed for Example

        /* Table 8/12 CT_PreTestStatuses */
        --SQL Removed for Example

        /* Table 9/12 CT_Facilities */
        --SQL Removed for Example

        /* Table 10/12 CT_HCVPositiveReferrals */
        --SQL Removed for Example

        /* Table 11/12 Service records for CT_HIVHCVTesting */
        --SQL Removed for Example

        /* Table 12/12 CT_HIVHCVTesting */
        --SQL Removed for Example


        ----------------------  Referrals Education 3 Tables    ----------------------------


        RAISERROR(N'%sReferrals Education Section DELETE', 0, 1, @CRLF) WITH NOWAIT; WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';


        /* Table 1/3 CT_EducationProvided */
        DELETE FROM @PKeys;     -- Reset Table Variable
        SET @PKeysLoaded   = 0; -- Reset PKeysLoaded for the next WHILE Loop
        SET   @RowsDeleted = 1; -- Set to 1 to start WHILE Loop
        WHILE @RowsDeleted > 0
        BEGIN
            BEGIN TRANSACTION

                /* Gather PKeys into PKeys table variable for DELETion */
                IF @PKeysLoaded = 0   /* If @PKeysLoaded = 0 this means the data has not yet been loaded into @PKeys */
                BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @PKeys (TablePKey)
                SELECT ep.EducationProvidedID
                FROM dbo.CT_ReferralsEducation ci
                INNER JOIN #ImportedAssessments      a ON a.AssessmentID = ci.AssessmentID
                INNER JOIN dbo.CT_EducationProvided ep ON ep.ParentID    = ci.ReferralsEducationID
                ;
                SET @PKeysLoaded = 1; /* Used to avoid loading the @PKeys TABLE Variable more than once WHILE in the Loop */
                END

                DELETE TOP(4500) ep
                FROM dbo.CT_EducationProvided ep
                WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @PKeys pk WHERE pk.TablePKey = ep.EducationProvidedID )

                SET    @RowsDeleted = @@ROWCOUNT;
                SELECT @TimeString  = ISNULL( CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), GETDATE() , 108), 'NoTime' )
                        , @Rows     = ISNULL( CAST(@RowsDeleted AS VARCHAR(10)), 'NoRows' )
                ;
                RAISERROR(N'CT_EducationProvided %s. Rows: %s', 0, 1, @TimeString, @Rows) WITH NOWAIT;  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';

            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END

        /* Table 2/3 CT_ReferralsProvided */
        --SQL Removed for Example

        /* Table 3/3 CT_ReferralsEducation */
        DELETE FROM @PKeys;     -- Reset Table Variable
        SET @PKeysLoaded   = 0; -- Reset PKeysLoaded for the next WHILE Loop
        SET   @RowsDeleted = 1; -- Set to 1 to start WHILE Loop
        WHILE @RowsDeleted > 0
        BEGIN
            BEGIN TRANSACTION

                /* Gather PKeys into PKeys table variable for DELETion */
                IF @PKeysLoaded = 0   /* If @PKeysLoaded = 0 this means the data has not yet been loaded into @PKeys */
                BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @PKeys (TablePKey)
                SELECT re.ReferralsEducationID
                FROM dbo.CT_ReferralsEducation re
                INNER JOIN #ImportedAssessments a ON a.AssessmentID = re.AssessmentID
                ;
                SET @PKeysLoaded = 1; /* Used to avoid loading the @PKeys TABLE Variable more than once WHILE in the Loop */
                END

                DELETE TOP(4500) re
                FROM dbo.CT_ReferralsEducation re
                WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @PKeys pk WHERE pk.TablePKey = re.ReferralsEducationID )

                SET    @RowsDeleted = @@ROWCOUNT;
                SELECT @TimeString  = ISNULL( CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), GETDATE() , 108), 'NoTime' )
                        , @Rows     = ISNULL( CAST(@RowsDeleted AS VARCHAR(10)), 'NoRows' )
                ;
                RAISERROR(N'CT_ReferralsEducation %s. Rows: %s', 0, 1, @TimeString, @Rows) WITH NOWAIT;  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';

            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END


        ----------------------  SSP SyringeServices 3 Tables    ----------------------------


        RAISERROR(N'%sSyringe Services Section DELETE', 0, 1, @CRLF) WITH NOWAIT; WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';


        /* Table 1/3 CT_SyringesDisposedHow */
        DELETE FROM @PKeys;     -- Reset Table Variable
        SET @PKeysLoaded   = 0; -- Reset PKeysLoaded for the next WHILE Loop
        SET   @RowsDeleted = 1; -- Set to 1 to start WHILE Loop
        WHILE @RowsDeleted > 0
        BEGIN
            BEGIN TRANSACTION

                /* Gather PKeys into PKeys table variable for DELETion */
                IF @PKeysLoaded = 0   /* If @PKeysLoaded = 0 this means the data has not yet been loaded into @PKeys */
                BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @PKeys (TablePKey)
                SELECT sd.SyringesDisposedHowID
                FROM dbo.CT_SyringeServices ci
                INNER JOIN #ImportedAssessments        a ON a.AssessmentID = ci.AssessmentID
                INNER JOIN dbo.CT_SyringesDisposedHow sd ON sd.ParentID = ci.SyringeServicesID
                ;
                SET @PKeysLoaded = 1; /* Used to avoid loading the @PKeys TABLE Variable more than once WHILE in the Loop */
                END

                DELETE TOP(4500) sd
                FROM dbo.CT_SyringesDisposedHow sd
                WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @PKeys pk WHERE pk.TablePKey = sd.SyringesDisposedHowID )

                SET    @RowsDeleted = @@ROWCOUNT;
                SELECT @TimeString  = ISNULL( CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), GETDATE() , 108), 'NoTime' )
                        , @Rows     = ISNULL( CAST(@RowsDeleted AS VARCHAR(10)), 'NoRows' )
                ;
                RAISERROR(N'CT_SyringesDisposedHow %s. Rows: %s', 0, 1, @TimeString, @Rows) WITH NOWAIT;  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';

            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END

        /* Table 2/3 Service records for CT_SyringeServices */
        --SQL Removed for Example

        /* Table 3/3 CT_SyringeServices */
        --SQL Removed for Example


        ----------------------  SSP FentanylTestStrip 5 Tables  ----------------------------


        RAISERROR(N'%sFentanyl Test Strips Section DELETE', 0, 1, @CRLF) WITH NOWAIT; WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';


        /* Table 1/5 CT_DrugUses */
        DELETE FROM @PKeys;     -- Reset Table Variable
        SET @PKeysLoaded   = 0; -- Reset PKeysLoaded for the next WHILE Loop
        SET   @RowsDeleted = 1; -- Set to 1 to start WHILE Loop
        WHILE @RowsDeleted > 0
        BEGIN
            BEGIN TRANSACTION

                /* Gather PKeys into PKeys table variable for DELETion */
                IF @PKeysLoaded = 0   /* If @PKeysLoaded = 0 this means the data has not yet been loaded into @PKeys */
                BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @PKeys (TablePKey)
                SELECT du.DrugUsesID
                FROM dbo.CT_FentanylAssessment ci
                INNER JOIN #ImportedAssessments      a ON a.AssessmentID           = ci.AssessmentID
                INNER JOIN dbo.CT_FentanylTestStrips ts ON ts.FentanylAssessmentID = ci.FentanylAssessmentID    
                INNER JOIN dbo.CT_DrugUses           du ON du.ParentID             = ts.FentanylTestStripsID
                ;
                SET @PKeysLoaded = 1; /* Used to avoid loading the @PKeys TABLE Variable more than once WHILE in the Loop */
                END

                DELETE TOP(4500) du
                FROM dbo.CT_DrugUses du
                WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @PKeys pk WHERE pk.TablePKey = du.DrugUsesID )

                SET    @RowsDeleted = @@ROWCOUNT;
                SELECT @TimeString  = ISNULL( CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), GETDATE() , 108), 'NoTime' )
                        , @Rows     = ISNULL( CAST(@RowsDeleted AS VARCHAR(10)), 'NoRows' )
                ;
                RAISERROR(N'CT_DrugUses %s. Rows: %s', 0, 1, @TimeString, @Rows) WITH NOWAIT;  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';

            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END

        /* Table 2/5 CT_OverdoseOutcomes */
        --SQL Removed for Example

        /* Table 3/5 CT_TestedDrugs */
        --SQL Removed for Example

        /* Table 4/5 CT_FentanylTestStrips */
        --SQL Removed for Example

        /* Table 5/5 CT_FentanylAssessment */
        --SQL Removed for Example


        ----------------------  Master Assessmnet 2 Tables      ----------------------------


        RAISERROR(N'%sMaster Assessmnet Section DELETE', 0, 1, @CRLF) WITH NOWAIT; WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';


        /* Table 1/2 CUSTOM_Assessment */
        DELETE FROM @PKeys;     -- Reset Table Variable
        SET @PKeysLoaded   = 0; -- Reset PKeysLoaded for the next WHILE Loop
        SET   @RowsDeleted = 1; -- Set to 1 to start WHILE Loop
        WHILE @RowsDeleted > 0
        BEGIN
            BEGIN TRANSACTION

                /* Gather PKeys into PKeys table variable for DELETion */
                IF @PKeysLoaded = 0   /* If @PKeysLoaded = 0 this means the data has not yet been loaded into @PKeys */
                BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @PKeys (TablePKey)
                SELECT ca.AssessmentID
                FROM dbo.CUSTOM_Assessment ca
                INNER JOIN #ImportedAssessments a ON a.AssessmentID = ca.AssessmentID
                ;
                SET @PKeysLoaded = 1; /* Used to avoid loading the @PKeys TABLE Variable more than once WHILE in the Loop */
                END

                DELETE TOP(4500) ca
                FROM dbo.CUSTOM_Assessment ca
                WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @PKeys pk WHERE pk.TablePKey = ca.AssessmentID )

                SET    @RowsDeleted = @@ROWCOUNT;
                SELECT @TimeString  = ISNULL( CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), GETDATE() , 108), 'NoTime' )
                        , @Rows     = ISNULL( CAST(@RowsDeleted AS VARCHAR(10)), 'NoRows' )
                ;
                RAISERROR(N'CUSTOM_Assessment %s. Rows: %s', 0, 1, @TimeString, @Rows) WITH NOWAIT;  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';

            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END

        /* Table 2/2 Assessment */
        DELETE FROM @PKeys;     -- Reset Table Variable
        SET @PKeysLoaded   = 0; -- Reset PKeysLoaded for the next WHILE Loop
        SET   @RowsDeleted = 1; -- Set to 1 to start WHILE Loop
        WHILE @RowsDeleted > 0
        BEGIN
            BEGIN TRANSACTION

                /* Gather PKeys into PKeys table variable for DELETion */
                IF @PKeysLoaded = 0   /* If @PKeysLoaded = 0 this means the data has not yet been loaded into @PKeys */
                BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @PKeys (TablePKey)
                SELECT aa.AssessmentID
                FROM dbo.Assessment aa
                INNER JOIN #ImportedAssessments a ON a.AssessmentID = aa.AssessmentID
                ;
                SET @PKeysLoaded = 1; /* Used to avoid loading the @PKeys TABLE Variable more than once WHILE in the Loop */
                END

                DELETE TOP(4500) aa
                FROM dbo.Assessment aa
                WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @PKeys pk WHERE pk.TablePKey = aa.AssessmentID )

                SET    @RowsDeleted = @@ROWCOUNT;
                SELECT @TimeString  = ISNULL( CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), GETDATE() , 108), 'NoTime' )
                        , @Rows     = ISNULL( CAST(@RowsDeleted AS VARCHAR(10)), 'NoRows' )
                ;
                RAISERROR(N'Assessment %s. Rows: %s', 0, 1, @TimeString, @Rows) WITH NOWAIT;  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';

            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END

        ------------------------------------------------------


        /* Output Time Stats */
        SET @DateTimeEnd = GETDATE();
    
        SELECT @TimeString = CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), @DateTimeEnd , 108);
        RAISERROR(N'%sProcess Completed at %s', 0, 1, @CRLF, @TimeString) WITH NOWAIT;  WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';

        -- Calculate the difference in seconds
        DECLARE @DiffInSeconds INT = DATEDIFF(SECOND, @DateTimeBeg, @DateTimeEnd);

        -- Calculate hours, minutes, and seconds from the total seconds
        DECLARE @Hours INT = @DiffInSeconds / 3600;
        DECLARE @Minutes INT = (@DiffInSeconds % 3600) / 60;
        DECLARE @Seconds INT = @DiffInSeconds % 60;

        -- Combine hours, minutes, and seconds into a time string
        DECLARE @TotalTimeString VARCHAR(8) = 
            RIGHT('0' + CAST(@Hours AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + ':' +
            RIGHT('0' + CAST(@Minutes AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + ':' +
            RIGHT('0' + CAST(@Seconds AS VARCHAR(2)), 2);

        RAISERROR(N'%sTotal Time: %s', 0, 1, @CRLF, @TotalTimeString) WITH NOWAIT; WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';

    
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK;
            PRINT 'Error occured: Open Transaction Detected.  Transaction ROLLED BACK';
        END
    
        /* DECLARE Individual Error Detail Variables */
        DECLARE @ErrorProcedure VARCHAR(200), @ErrorMessage     NVARCHAR(4000), @ErrorSeverity  VARCHAR(20), @ErrorLine     VARCHAR(20)
            , @ErrorState       VARCHAR(20) /* Error State = Level aka Severity Level */
        ;

        /* Store Individual Error Details in variables for later output */
        SELECT  @ErrorProcedure = ERROR_PROCEDURE(), @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(), @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE(), @ErrorLine = ERROR_LINE();
        --ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber

        /* RAISE the Error */
        RAISERROR(N'An error occurred in %s Deleting Assessment Records.  Level %s, State %s, Line %s, ErrorMsg: %s', 11, 2, @ErrorProcedure, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState, @ErrorLine, @ErrorMessage);
        RETURN;
    
    END CATCH

END
```

**I've included links below as to what led me to create this NEW version.  Again I did not discover any examples that show how to do this in the real world with a Complex example DELETING from multiple tables in a single script**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24785439/deleting-1-millions-rows-in-sql-server

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11230225/how-to-efficiently-delete-rows-while-not-using-truncate-table-in-a-500-000-rows

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138593/delete-large-amount-of-data-in-sql-server

https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151497/discussion-on-question-by-code-novice-properly-delete-500k-rows-from-multiple-t); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.